# FFMPEG avoid_negative_ts makes video start not from keyframe

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

Let's say I want to cut part of the mp4 video and resize it from 1280x720 to 854x480.

My command looks like this:

```
ffmpeg -ss 45 -i source.mp4 -ss 10 -to 20 \
-acodec aac -ar 44100 -ac 2 -c:v libx264 \
-crf 26 -vf scale=854:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=854:480:0:0,setsar=1/1,setdar=16/9 \
-video_track_timescale 29971 -pix_fmt yuv420p \
-map_metadata 0 -avoid_negative_ts 1 -y dest.mp4
```

The problem is, when I don't use option `avoid_negative_ts`, resulting video has some issues with time bases etc, therefore it cannot be later converted by other libs, for example Swift's `AVFoundation`.

But when I use this option - video does not start with keyframe.
By using ffprobe I see `start_time=0.065997` or other times other than 0.

How can I use option `avoid_negative_ts` and have a video that starts with keyframe?

Comment: Since you're re-encoding the video, the output will always start with a keyframe. For fps 29.97, your timescale should be 30000.

Comment: @Gyan but in fact output does not start with a keyframe.

Comment: How are you checking? Paste the command and its output.

Comment: @Gyan you can see output here: https://pastebin.com/iUT0ArA2 . Notice line 35, `start_time=0.066000`. It says that video stream starts from 0.066000. I want it to start from 0.000.

My bad, video may start from keyframe, but video stream does not start from 0.000